# Multiple alignments in a tabularx table

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment, tabularx

I'd like to build a 2-column table, where the first column is horizontally and vertically centered while the second one is only aligned to the left. I came up with the following code but it doesn't look that good. Could you give me some advice please? Thanks!

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ p{30 mm} | >{\arraybackslash}X  }
  Cas & $\Delta_{\alpha}$ \\
   \hline
   $x_1 < x_2, y_1, y_2$ & $\alpha - \big[w_{22'} + \mu(1)(R_{max} - w_{21'} - w_{22'}) +  \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) \big]$\\ 
   \hline
   $x_2 < x_1, y_1, y_2$ & $\alpha - \big[R_{max} - w_{11'} + \mu(1)(w_{11'} + w_{12'} - R_{max}) + \nu(1)(w_{11'} - w_{12'}) \big]$ \\
   \hline
   $y_1 < x_1, x_2, y_2$ & $\alpha - \big[w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'}  - w_{22'}) + \nu(1)(R_{max} - w_{12'} - w_{22'}) \big]$ \\
   \hline
   $y_2 < x_1, x_2, y_1$ & $\alpha - \big[R_{max} - w_{11'} + \mu(1)(w_{11'} - w_{21'}) + \nu(1)(w_{11'} + w_{21'} - R_{max}) \big] $ \\
   \hline
   $x_1 = y_1 < x_2 = y_2$ & $\alpha - \big[w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (R_{max} - w_{21'} - w_{12'})  \big]$\\ 
   \hline
   $x_1 = y_2 < x_2 = y_1$ & $\alpha - \big[w_{22'} + \mu(1)(R_{max} - w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (w_{11'} - w_{22'} - R_{max})  \big]$ \\
   \hline
   $x_2 = y_1 < x_1 = y_2$ & $\alpha - \big[w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(R_{max} - w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (w_{11'} - w_{22'} - R_{max})  \big]$ \\
   \hline
   $x_2 = y_2 < x_1 = y_1$ & $\alpha - \big[R_{max} - w_{11'} + \mu(1)(w_{11'} + w_{12'} - R_{max}) + \nu(1')(w_{11'} + w_{21'} - R_{max}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (R_{max} - w_{12'} - w_{21'}) \big]$ \\
   \hline
   $x_1 = x_2 = y_1 = y_2$ & $\alpha - \big[w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (w_{11'} + w_{22'} - w_{12'} - w_{21'}) \big]$
 \end{tabularx} 
\end{center}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ c | >{\arraybackslash}X  }` should get you closer to the expected alignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestions, in no particular order:

- Use `c` instead of `p` as the column type for the first column. Actually, I think `l` is even better, so that's what I used in the code below.
- Keep using a `tabularx` environment, and run `\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}` to impose vertical centering (as opposed to top-alignment) for non-`X` columns
- Enable automatic math mode by using `>{$}l<{$}` and `>{$}L<{$}` instead of just `l` and `L`. That way, you can get rid of lots of `$` symbols in the table; this, in turn, really helps to declutter the code.
- No need to enlarge the square brackets.
- Get rid of the vertical rule, load the `booktabs` package, and replace `\hline`, as needed, with either `\midrule` or `\addlinespace`. Remember that whitespace can be every bit as effective a separator as a solid line. Consider using `\bottomrule` -- you guessed it -- at the bottom of the `tabularx` environment.
- Write `R_{\max}`, not `R_{max}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight}X}
\renewcommand\tabularxcolumn[1]{m{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} >{$}l<{$} >{$}L<{$} @{}}
   \mbox{Cas} & \Delta_{\alpha} \\
   \midrule
   x_1 < x_2, y_1, y_2 & \alpha - [w_{22'} + \mu(1)(R_{\max} - w_{21'} - w_{22'}) +  \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) ]\\ 
   \addlinespace
   x_2 < x_1, y_1, y_2 & \alpha - [R_{\max} - w_{11'} + \mu(1)(w_{11'} + w_{12'} - R_{\max}) + \nu(1)(w_{11'} - w_{12'}) ] \\
   \addlinespace
   y_1 < x_1, x_2, y_2 & \alpha - [w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'}  - w_{22'}) + \nu(1)(R_{\max} - w_{12'} - w_{22'}) ] \\
   \addlinespace
   y_2 < x_1, x_2, y_1 & \alpha - [R_{\max} - w_{11'} + \mu(1)(w_{11'} - w_{21'}) + \nu(1)(w_{11'} + w_{21'} - R_{\max}) ]  \\
   \addlinespace
   x_1 = y_1 < x_2 = y_2 & \alpha - [w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (R_{\max} - w_{21'} - w_{12'})  ]\\ 
   \addlinespace
   x_1 = y_2 < x_2 = y_1 & \alpha - [w_{22'} + \mu(1)(R_{\max} - w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (w_{11'} - w_{22'} - R_{\max})  ] \\
   \addlinespace
   x_2 = y_1 < x_1 = y_2 & \alpha - [w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(R_{\max} - w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (w_{11'} - w_{22'} - R_{\max})  ] \\
   \addlinespace
   x_2 = y_2 < x_1 = y_1 & \alpha - [R_{\max} - w_{11'} + \mu(1)(w_{11'} + w_{12'} - R_{\max}) + \nu(1')(w_{11'} + w_{21'} - R_{\max}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (R_{\max} - w_{12'} - w_{21'}) ] \\
   \addlinespace
   x_1 = x_2 = y_1 = y_2 & \alpha - [w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (w_{11'} + w_{22'} - w_{12'} - w_{21'}) ] \\
   \bottomrule
\end{tabularx} 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The table code is much shorter id you will be willing to use the  `tabularray`  package:

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {@{} c X[l,m] @{}},
             rowsep=4pt
             }
   \mbox{Cas} & \Delta_{\alpha}     \\
   \hline
x_1 < x_2, y_1, y_2 & \alpha - [w_{22'} + \mu(1)(R_{\max} - w_{21'} - w_{22'}) +  \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) ]        \\

x_2 < x_1, y_1, y_2 & \alpha - [R_{\max} - w_{11'} + \mu(1)(w_{11'} + w_{12'} - R_{\max}) + \nu(1)(w_{11'} - w_{12'}) ] \\

y_1 < x_1, x_2, y_2 & \alpha - [w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'}  - w_{22'}) + \nu(1)(R_{\max} - w_{12'} - w_{22'}) ] \\

y_2 < x_1, x_2, y_1 & \alpha - [R_{\max} - w_{11'} + \mu(1)(w_{11'} - w_{21'}) + \nu(1)(w_{11'} + w_{21'} - R_{\max}) ]  \\

x_1 = y_1 < x_2 = y_2 & \alpha - [w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (R_{\max} - w_{21'} - w_{12'})  ]\\

x_1 = y_2 < x_2 = y_1 & \alpha - [w_{22'} + \mu(1)(R_{\max} - w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (w_{11'} - w_{22'} - R_{\max})  ] \\

x_2 = y_1 < x_1 = y_2 & \alpha - [w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(R_{\max} - w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (w_{11'} - w_{22'} - R_{\max})  ] \\

x_2 = y_2 < x_1 = y_1 & \alpha - [R_{\max} - w_{11'} + \mu(1)(w_{11'} + w_{12'} - R_{\max}) + \nu(1')(w_{11'} + w_{21'} - R_{\max}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (R_{\max} - w_{12'} - w_{21'}) ] \\

x_1 = x_2 = y_1 = y_2 & \alpha - [w_{22'} + \mu(1)(w_{12'} - w_{22'}) + \nu(1')(w_{21'} - w_{22'}) + \mu(1) \nu(1') (w_{11'} + w_{22'} - w_{12'} - w_{21'}) ] \\
   \hline
\end{tblr}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]